# How to convert from numpy array to file byte object?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I read an image file as

```
with open('abc.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    a = f.read()
```

On the other hand, I use `cv2` to read the same file

```
b = cv2.imread('abc.jpg', -1)
```

How to convert `b` to `a` directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer to your question:

```
success, a_numpy = cv2.imencode('.jpg', b)
a = a_numpy.tostring()
```

### Things you should know:

First, `type(a)` is a binary string, and `type(b)` is a numpy array. It's easy to convert between those types, since you can make `np.array(binary_string)` to go from string to numpy, and `np_array.tostring()` to go from numpy to binary string.

However, `a` and `b` represent different things. In the string `a`, you're reading the JPEG encoded version of the image, and in `b` you have the decoded image. You can check that `len(b.tostring())` is **massively larger** than `len(a)`. You need to know which one you want to use. Also, keep in mind that each time you encode a JPEG, you will loose some quality.

### How to save an image to disk:

Your question looks like you want an encoded binary string. The only use I can imagine for that is dumping it to the disk (or sending it over http?).

To save the image on your disk, you can use

```
cv2.imwrite('my_file.jpg', b)
```

Comment: Thank you, Marco. I need to read a gif file from the web and convert all its frames to binary string.